# Why is my reqMktData thread not running with IB TWS Python API?

Tags: python, multithreading, interactive-brokers

I can't figure out why my streamData thread is not running, while the my con_thread is running fine.
I know from using this piece of code in larger scripts that they do, in fact, receive the market data just fine from using this function and thread, so I can't understand why the con_thread being alive is True, while the stream_thread being alive is False. Any idea?

```
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.contract import Contract
import threading
import time

class TradingApp(EWrapper, EClient):

    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self,self)

    def error(self, reqId, errorCode, errorString):
        print("Error. Id: ", reqId, " Code: ", errorCode, " Msg: ", errorString)

Underlying = Contract()
Underlying.localSymbol = "MESU2"
Underlying.secType = "FUT"
Underlying.currency = "USD"
Underlying.exchange = "GLOBEX"

def websocket_con():
    app.run()

def streamData():
    app.reqMarketDataType(2)
    app.reqMktData(3002, Underlying, "", False, False, [])

app = TradingApp()
app.connect("127.0.0.1", 7497, 3002)

time.sleep(1)

con_thread = threading.Thread(target=websocket_con, daemon=True)
con_thread.start()
time.sleep(1)

stream_thread = threading.Thread(target=streamData())
stream_thread.start()
time.sleep(1)

while True:
    print("conthread",con_thread.is_alive())
    print("streamthread",stream_thread.is_alive())
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: It's a typo. When you create the `streamData` thread, you're actually calling `streamData` in the main thread, and passing its result as the `target` parameter.  You need `threading.Thread(target=streamData)`, without the `()`.

Comment: Hi @TimRoberts, thank you for the quick response. I tried running what you suggest but I am getting the same output. Did you run this and are getting two True? I still get a False for the streamData thread

Comment: @TimRoberts I was thinking it was not working because the market/exchange was closed but I just tried again with the futures market being open, and while I'm getting the pricing data back correctly, the thread still comes back as not live. Any additional clue?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting.  Your `stream_thread` does one thing and then exits.  Are you expecting it to loop somehow?

Comment: @TimRoberts yes I think I expected it to stay alive but that was my mistake. See answer from Mayank and my comment to it. Thanks!

Comment: Right.  The thread only stays alive until the function returns.  `app.run` presumably calls a loop to maintain contact with the sever, but your other thread just calls two functions which return rather quickly.  In fact, there's not much point in using a thread.  Just call `streamData()` inline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all please update how you are passing the function argument to the thread. No parenthesis after the function name. You are passing the function as a parameter not executing the function.

```
stream_thread = threading.Thread(target=streamData)
```

Secondly, why do you expect the stream_thread.is_alive() to return True? The function is complete and the websocket connection has been established and therefore it returns false. It will return True only till the streamData function is incomplete. If you want to test it, add a line time.sleep(10) within your streamData function and you will see it returning True for the stream_thread for 10 seconds.

However, please note that your streaming is happening in the background although your code is not handling the streaming data. You will need an appropriate EWrapper function in your TradingApp. Something like below

```
def tickPrice(self, reqId, tickType, price, attrib):
    super().tickPrice(reqId, tickType, price, attrib)
    print("TickPrice. TickerId:", reqId, "tickType:", tickType, "Price:", price)
```

Comment: Hi Mayank, thank you for the explanation. I suppose that after reading that thread couldn't be killed in python etc., and after seeing some of my other threads like the con_thread staying alive, I thought it would be the same for the stream_thread but your explanation makes sense. I have done some tests and I do see the stream_thread being alive before dying.